# Spring Integration and User interface

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I have a user interface where I can add or delete FTP servers (adding the port and username..etc) those are persisted in a postgres DB, my app will read what connections are in the DB using spring MVC and Spring Integration for dynamic FTP (I'm using delegating session factory and Rotating advice) the app is working when I run it and reads what is available connections in the DB and accordingly will transfer what is available in the FTP directory that I specified. My issue is that if I use the interface to delete or add new server, the app is not taking the new connections that are persisted in the DB unless I stop it and run it again, I want to make it work on runtime when I add and delete servers to be taken automatically.
Here is my conf class that I'm using for setting the Integration flow, I'm not sure if there is any annotation to get this working. can someone please guide?
Do let me know if more information is needed

```
    @Configuration
@Component
@EnableIntegration
public class FTIntegration {

    public static final String TIMEZONE_UTC = "UTC";
    public static final String TIMESTAMP_FORMAT_OF_FILES = "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS";
    public static final String TEMPORARY_FILE_SUFFIX = ".part";
    public static final int POLLER_FIXED_PERIOD_DELAY = 5000;
    public static final int MAX_MESSAGES_PER_POLL = 100;


    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FTIntegration.class);
    private static final String CHANNEL_INTERMEDIATE_STAGE = "intermediateChannel";

     @Autowired
    private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

    /* pulling the server config from postgres DB*/

    private final BranchRepository branchRepository;

    @Value("${app.temp-dir}")
    private String localTempPath;

    public FTIntegration(BranchRepository branchRepository) {
        this.branchRepository = branchRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public Branch myBranch(){
        return new Branch();
    }

    /**
     * The default poller with 5s, 100 messages, RotatingServerAdvice and transaction.
     *
     * @return default poller.
     */
    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata poller(){
        return Pollers
                .fixedDelay(POLLER_FIXED_PERIOD_DELAY)
                .maxMessagesPerPoll(MAX_MESSAGES_PER_POLL)
                .transactional()
                .get();
    }

    /**
     * The direct channel for the flow.
     *
     * @return MessageChannel
     */
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel stockIntermediateChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    /**
     * Get the files from a remote directory. Add a timestamp to the filename
     * and write them to a local temporary folder.
     *
     * @return IntegrationFlow
     */

    public IntegrationFlow fileInboundFlowFromFTPServer(Branch myBranch){

        final FtpInboundChannelAdapterSpec sourceSpecFtp = Ftp.inboundAdapter(createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch))
                .preserveTimestamp(true)
                .patternFilter("*.csv")
                .deleteRemoteFiles(true)
                .maxFetchSize(MAX_MESSAGES_PER_POLL)
                .remoteDirectory(myBranch.getFolderPath())
                .localDirectory(new File(localTempPath))
                .temporaryFileSuffix(TEMPORARY_FILE_SUFFIX)
                .localFilenameExpression(new FunctionExpression<String>(s -> {
                    final int fileTypeSepPos = s.lastIndexOf('.');
                    return DateTimeFormatter
                            .ofPattern(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT_OF_FILES)
                            .withZone(ZoneId.of(TIMEZONE_UTC))
                            .format(Instant.now())
                            + "_"
                            + s.substring(0,fileTypeSepPos)
                            + s.substring(fileTypeSepPos);
                }));

        // Poller definition
        final Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec> stockInboundPoller = endpointConfigurer -> endpointConfigurer
                .id("stockInboundPoller")
                .autoStartup(true)
                .poller(poller());

        IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
                .from(sourceSpecFtp, stockInboundPoller)
                .transform(File.class, p ->{
                    // log step
                    LOG.info("flow=stockInboundFlowFromAFT, message=incoming file: " + p);
                    return p;
                })
                .channel(CHANNEL_INTERMEDIATE_STAGE)
                .get();


       // this.flowContext.registration(flow).id(myBranch.getId().toString()).register().toString();
        //this.flowContext.registration(flow).id("fileInb").register();
        return flow;
    }

   @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow stockIntermediateStageChannel() {
        IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
                .from(CHANNEL_INTERMEDIATE_STAGE)
                .transform(p -> {
                    //log step
                    LOG.info("flow=stockIntermediateStageChannel, message=rename file: " + p);
                    return p;
                })
                //TODO
                .channel(new NullChannel())
                .get();
        return flow;

    }

    public DefaultFtpSessionFactory createNewFtpSessionFactory(Branch branch){
        final DefaultFtpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        factory.setHost(branch.getHost());
        factory.setUsername(branch.getUsern());
        factory.setPort(branch.getFtpPort());
        factory.setPassword(branch.getPassword());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Here is the controller part for deleting a server.

```
@Controller
public class BranchController {

    private BranchService branchService;

    private BranchToBranchForm branchToBranchForm;

    //@Autowired
    private Branch branch;

    @Autowired
    private FTIntegration ftIntegration;


    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FTIntegration.class);
    private static final String CHANNEL_INTERMEDIATE_STAGE = "intermediateChannel";


    @Autowired
    private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

    @Autowired
    public void setBranchService(BranchService branchService) {
        this.branchService = branchService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setBranchToBranchForm(BranchToBranchForm branchToBranchForm) {
        this.branchToBranchForm = branchToBranchForm;
    }

    @RequestMapping( "/")
    public String branch(){return "redirect:/branch/list";}

    @RequestMapping({"/branch/list","/branch"})
    public String listBranches(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("branches",branchService.listAll());
        return "branch/list";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/branch/showbranch/{id}")
    public String getBranch (@PathVariable String id, Model model){
       model.addAttribute("branch", branchService.getById(Long.valueOf(id)));
       //addFlowFtp(id);
       addFlowftp(id);
        return "/branch/showbranch";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/branch/edit/{id}")
    public String edit(@PathVariable String id, Model model){
        Branch branch = branchService.getById(Long.valueOf(id));
        BranchForm branchForm = branchToBranchForm.convert(branch);
        model.addAttribute("branchForm",branchForm);
        return "branch/branchform";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/branch/new")
    public String newBranch(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("branchForm", new BranchForm());
         return "branch/branchform";
    }

       @RequestMapping(value = "/branch", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveOrUpdateBranch(@Valid BranchForm branchForm, BindingResult bindingResult){

        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return "branch/branchform";
        }

        Branch savedBranch = branchService.saveOrUpdateBranchForm(branchForm);
        return "redirect:/branch/showbranch/" + savedBranch.getId();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/branch/delete/{id}")
    private String delete(@PathVariable String id){
        branchService.delete(Long.valueOf(id));
        flowContext.remove(id);
        return "redirect:/branch/list";
    }

    private void addFlowftp(String name) {
        branch = branchService.getById(Long.valueOf(name));
        System.out.println(branch.getBranchCode());

        IntegrationFlow flow = ftIntegration.fileInboundFlowFromFTPServer(branch);

        this.flowContext.registration(flow).id(name).register();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Dynamic and runtime Integration Flows](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/java-dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows).

You can add/remove integration flows at runtime using the techniques described there.

**EDIT**

Here is an example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class So53042903Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So53042903Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/add/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String add(@PathVariable String name) {
        addFlow(name);
        System.out.println("added " + name);
        return "added " + name;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/remove/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String remove(@PathVariable String name) {
        this.flowContext.remove(name);
        System.out.println("removed " + name);
        return "removed " + name;
    }

    private void addFlow(String name) {
        IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(() -> "processing: " + name, e -> e
                    .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(3_000)))
                .log(Level.INFO, "foo", "payload")
                .get();
        this.flowContext.registration(flow).id(name).register();
    }

}
```

and

```
added foo
2018-10-31 10:22:58.998  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-1] foo                                      : processing: foo
2018-10-31 10:23:02.001  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-1] foo                                      : processing: foo
2018-10-31 10:23:05.002  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-2] foo                                      : processing: foo
2018-10-31 10:23:07.312  INFO 1768 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {bridge} as a subscriber to the 'bar.channel#1' channel
2018-10-31 10:23:07.312  INFO 1768 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.bar.channel#1' has 1 subscriber(s).
2018-10-31 10:23:07.312  INFO 1768 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bar.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
2018-10-31 10:23:07.312  INFO 1768 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : started bar.org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean#0
added bar
2018-10-31 10:23:07.312  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-3] foo                                      : processing: bar
2018-10-31 10:23:08.008  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-1] foo                                      : processing: foo
2018-10-31 10:23:10.316  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-2] foo                                      : processing: bar
2018-10-31 10:23:11.009  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-4] foo                                      : processing: foo
2018-10-31 10:23:13.318  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-5] foo                                      : processing: bar
2018-10-31 10:23:14.011  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-3] foo                                      : processing: foo
2018-10-31 10:23:16.322  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-6] foo                                      : processing: bar
2018-10-31 10:23:16.614  INFO 1768 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {bridge} as a subscriber to the 'baz.channel#1' channel
2018-10-31 10:23:16.614  INFO 1768 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.baz.channel#1' has 1 subscriber(s).
2018-10-31 10:23:16.614  INFO 1768 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started baz.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
2018-10-31 10:23:16.614  INFO 1768 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : started baz.org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean#0
added baz
2018-10-31 10:23:16.614  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-7] foo                                      : processing: baz
2018-10-31 10:23:17.012  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-1] foo                                      : processing: foo
2018-10-31 10:23:19.323  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-2] foo                                      : processing: bar
2018-10-31 10:23:19.615  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-8] foo                                      : processing: baz
2018-10-31 10:23:20.014  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-4] foo                                      : processing: foo
2018-10-31 10:23:22.324  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-9] foo                                      : processing: bar
2018-10-31 10:23:22.622  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-5] foo                                      : processing: baz
2018-10-31 10:23:23.015  INFO 1768 --- [sk-scheduler-10] foo                                      : processing: foo
2018-10-31 10:23:25.326  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-3] foo                                      : processing: bar
2018-10-31 10:23:25.623  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-6] foo                                      : processing: baz
2018-10-31 10:23:26.020  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-7] foo                                      : processing: foo
2018-10-31 10:23:27.966  INFO 1768 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : stopped bar.org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean#0
2018-10-31 10:23:27.966  INFO 1768 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {bridge} as a subscriber to the 'bar.channel#1' channel
2018-10-31 10:23:27.966  INFO 1768 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.bar.channel#1' has 0 subscriber(s).
2018-10-31 10:23:27.966  INFO 1768 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped bar.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
removed bar
2018-10-31 10:23:28.624  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-1] foo                                      : processing: baz
2018-10-31 10:23:29.025  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-8] foo                                      : processing: foo
2018-10-31 10:23:31.625  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-4] foo                                      : processing: baz
2018-10-31 10:23:32.026  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-9] foo                                      : processing: foo
2018-10-31 10:23:34.626  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-5] foo                                      : processing: baz
2018-10-31 10:23:35.027  INFO 1768 --- [sk-scheduler-10] foo                                      : processing: foo
2018-10-31 10:23:35.931  INFO 1768 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : stopped baz.org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean#0
2018-10-31 10:23:35.931  INFO 1768 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {bridge} as a subscriber to the 'baz.channel#1' channel
2018-10-31 10:23:35.931  INFO 1768 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.baz.channel#1' has 0 subscriber(s).
2018-10-31 10:23:35.932  INFO 1768 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped baz.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
removed baz
2018-10-31 10:23:38.032  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-3] foo                                      : processing: foo
2018-10-31 10:23:41.036  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-3] foo                                      : processing: foo
2018-10-31 10:23:44.037  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-3] foo                                      : processing: foo
2018-10-31 10:23:47.041  INFO 1768 --- [ask-scheduler-3] foo                                      : processing: foo
2018-10-31 10:23:47.736  INFO 1768 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : stopped foo.org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean#0
2018-10-31 10:23:47.736  INFO 1768 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {bridge} as a subscriber to the 'foo.channel#1' channel
2018-10-31 10:23:47.736  INFO 1768 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.foo.channel#1' has 0 subscriber(s).
2018-10-31 10:23:47.736  INFO 1768 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped foo.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
removed foo
2018-10-31 10:23:51.349  INFO 1768 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] inMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin : Application shutdown requested.
2018-10-31 10:23:51.350  INFO 1768 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2018-10-31 10:23:51.350  INFO 1768 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2018-10-31 10:23:51.351  INFO 1768 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2018-10-31 10:23:51.351  INFO 1768 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2018-10-31 10:23:51.352  INFO 1768 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

Comment: Below is my follow up on this issue, hope you can guide me through the correct steps...thank you

Comment: See my comment on your answer. Also `this.flowContext.registration(flow).register();` - you must keep a reference to the registration and call `flowContext.remove(registration.getId()` to stop and remove the flow.

Comment: Yup somehow new here and to spring integration :) , below is deleted now. so according to your reply where should I put the flowContect.remove(..), I'm sorry but totally new and trying to scratch my head on that most the day @Gary Russel

Comment: You said you "remove it from the DB" someplace - simply remove the flow from the context in the same place. The documentation I pointed you to says `You can use the IntegrationFlowRegistration.destroy() callback to remove a dynamically registered IntegrationFlow and all its dependent beans when you no longer need them.`. That calls `flowContext.remove(this.iid)` so it does the same thing,

Comment: Yes correct, I'm removing it using a controller class and a function as per below, so should that be there? or in the class I have above that contains the integration flows?I'm using a web page to add or delete servers to the DB.
@RequestMapping("/branch/delete/{id}")
private String delete(@PathVariable String id){
 branchService.delete(Long.valueOf(id));
        return "redirect:/branch/list";
}
@Gary Russell

Comment: I registered the the Integration flow and gave it id "fileInb" and the controller method for deleting a server I used flowContext.remove("fileInb"), this worked to remove the integration flow when I delete a server, but it also stopping to poll from the other server(s) that are still there in the DB, seems that this is removing the whole flow, I tried to add a new server but it is not running again the flow anymore, I'm editing my code so you can see what I updated and what I'm getting the consol when I delete server, it started to become interesting now @Gary Russell

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it's hard to read; edit the question instead. What you are suggesting makes no sense; the flows are independent; removing one won't affect others. The message is what I would expect to see. I will add a simple sample to my answer.

Comment: I have edited my question with new code where Im registering and where I'm removing the flow from the controller, I know it does not make sense but this is what is happening, lets say I have two servers one in Beirut and one in Dubai which are in the DB and being monitored by the flow, so I removed the Beirut one from the delete in the controller , then Dubai is not being polled, I know im doing something wrong in the code as I'm new to this and appreciate the help you are giving - will be waiting your example so I can compare my coding@Gary Russell

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Ex clarifies how to use add/remove which helped a lot, however in my exercise I'm using delegating session and advice that contain the servers and then those are passed to the flow as a parameter in the from() , I assume when I register the flow it is registering the whole list of servers with one ID and when I remove one server it is removing them all? not sure if we can go to sub registry or something, I might be totally wrong with my understanding. My code is in two classes one for the config (SFTIntegration) and one for Controller (BranchController), sorry for the hard time @Garry Russell

Comment: For your application, you need a flow for each server instead of a delegating session factory. Declare the main flow as a `@Bean` then add a dynamic "mini" flow for each. `adapter->channel("mainFlowChannel")` then register/remove each of these.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that way as well, I will try to get that done and update my conclusion here, your input on this was very helpful and moved me on the project big time...thanks @Gary Russell.

Comment: I declared the main flow Bean and passed an argument as Branch in which will create Session factory to open the connection, then I created a flow "mini" in the controller to that will add a flow for every branch and then registering and removing, I'm facing an issue when I run the app as it is not running, code is updated to the latest as well as the error...if you can show me where I have went wrong here..@Gary Russell

Comment: The main flow should start with `.from("someChannel")`; then each new mini flow should be `from(Ftp....).channel("someChannel")`. The adapter itself can't be in a `@Bean`.

Comment: As what I understood from your help, I was able to manage this by removing the bean where I'm using the adaptor and by calling the method from the controller and passing the branch I'm adding as a parameter then registering it in a mini flow in the control so that I can delete if I want..I edited the code to show as latest, is this the way you are guiding me to do?Just want to confirm so that I move to the next step, thank you @Gary Russell

Comment: Yes; that is what I meant.

Comment: Perfect, so now I want to process the file and generate new output then send it back to the same server, I can do the same process but with outbound adaptor?as I'm checking some examples but couldn't get to a solution since I'm new to the outbound as well, will continue looking for possible solutions, I will have to do the same in matter of register and delete for the outbound.@Gary Russell

Comment: This comment thread is getting too long; I suggest you start a new question showing what you have tried.